# For the purpose of a job application, how do I know if I am compliant with 15 C.F.R. 730?

Tags: job-search, united-states

I read in a job listing that the position may require that I have legal authorization to access controlled technology per the definition in the Export Administration Regulations 15 C.F.R. 730 and am "immediately eligible".

I skimmed through this regulation and I don't specifically see anything which indicates how one obtains or is eligible under this section.  Is there a certification that one has to obtain?  Is it like a background check?  Or is something like being a U.S. citizen sufficient?  How do I know if I meet this requirement in the listing?  Maybe this is something I don't have to worry about because the company would provide this, or maybe having to ask means I'm not immediately eligible, but in any case that phrase triggers me to try to research ahead of time and be prepared to answer should they ask me.

Answer (score 6):

Export Administration Regulations 15 C.F.R 730 is a regulation against the export of technology/knowledge to foreign entities/persons.

You would have to be an American Citizen to be eligible. You will definitely have to pass a background check, and it is possible that there might be more involved which they are not allowed to list in the job description.

"having to ask means I am not eligible" there are so many government regulations that it is practically impossible for anyone to know them all, and have a practical skillset in their head at the same time. So, no... Asking what does poorly worded government regulation mean? And does it exclude me does not mean that it excludes you...

If you pass the phone interview for a job like this you will have the opportunity to meet with their security officer. This is the person whose job it is to know all of the government red tape/regulations. You should ask them about everything that you are worried about. This will help you decide if you are willing to live with the restrictions that the job will place on your personnel life, if you can get the job, and a bunch of other things. Do not waste the opportunity to have a good Q&A session.